# OpenCV's `getTextSize` and `putText` return wrong size and chop letters with lower pixels

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following Python code:

```
FONT = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
FONT_SCALE = 1.0
FONT_THICKNESS = 2
bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
label_color = (0, 0, 0)

label = 'Propaganda'
label_width, label_height = cv2.getTextSize(label, FONT, FONT_SCALE, FONT_THICKNESS)[0]
label_patch = np.zeros((label_height, label_width, 3), np.uint8)
label_patch[:,:] = bg_color
```

I create a new blank image, with the size returned by `getTextSize`, and then, I add the text at the bottom-left point, according to the docs, which is `x = 0, y = (height - 1)` and with the same font, scale and thickness parameters used for `getTextSize`

```
cv2.putText(label_patch, label, (0, label_height - 1), FONT, FONT_SCALE, label_color, FONT_THICKNESS)
```

But when I use `imshow` or `imwrite` on the image `label_patch`, this is the results I get:

[image]

It can easily be seen that lowercase  `p` and lowercase `g` are cut in the middle, such that `g` and `a` cannot even be distinguished. How can I make OpenCV's `getTextSize` return the correct size, and how can I make OpenCV's `putText` start drawing the text from the actual lowest point?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem, so sharing it here.

It turns out that there is another parameter that `getTextSize` returns, which is the  `baseline`. It should have been taken into account when creating the box: the box height should be `label_height + baseline`:

```
(label_width, label_height), baseline = cv2.getTextSize(label, FONT, FONT_SCALE, FONT_THICKNESS)
label_patch = np.zeros((label_height + baseline, label_width, 3), np.uint8)
label_patch[:,:] = bg_color
```

Now, adding the text at the same point as before, which means that the baseline pixels will remain below (the point has actually moved one pixel down, as advised by @api55):

```
cv2.putText(label_patch, label, (0, label_height), FONT, FONT_SCALE, label_color, FONT_THICKNESS)
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I was just writing it jeje, also, you can remove the -1 from the height from the putText and you will get a better P

Comment: Another tip I could give from my short experience with OpenCV's `putText`, is always use `font_scale=1`, and if you want to scale it, do it manually using OpenCV's `resize` (and choose an interpolation method depending on if you want to scale it up or down), since using a font scale that is not `1` usually produces a distorted result

Comment: @api55 Thank you!. This is indeed much better. Took me more than 2 years, but fixed it eventually.